# Access to the nested structure in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm designing an API and a database structure for educational courses with the following hierarchy: Course -> Module -> Lesson -> Topic -> Tasks (Body).

```js
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('a...')
     
        name: "How to cook borscht",
     
        modules: [
            {
                id: ObjectId('b...'), // Perhaps not ObjectId, I haven't figured it out yet.
                title: "Analyzing the composition",
     
                lessons: [
                    {
                        id: ObjectId('c...'),
                        title: "Selecting the Cabbage"
     
                        topics: [
                            id: ObjectId('d...'),
                            title: "White Cabbage",
     
                            tasks: [
                                 id: ObjectId('e...'),
                                 description: "White cabbage is a common vegetable crop, one of the cultivated variants of the species Brassica oleracea."
                            ]        
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

It is assumed that the first request to /api/courses will return the course structure to the user as a program description. Then, to start learning, I need to return the first lesson `topics[0]` with all the assignments.

```js
modules[$id].lessons[$id].topics[$id].tasks
```

After completing a lesson, it's intended to record that it's been completed (this might require a separate table with a list of users and their activity). It's assumed that all course content will be stored in one document, and there may be different translations (there is a possibility that the document size will exceed 16MB).

Question: How to design the document structure to efficiently retrieve a list of tasks for a specific course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Course document
{
  "_id": ObjectId("a..."),
  "name": "How to cook borscht",
  "modules": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("b..."),
      "title": "Analyzing the composition",
      "lessons": [
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("c..."),
          "title": "Selecting the Cabbage",
          "topics": [
            {
              "_id": ObjectId("d..."),
              "title": "White Cabbage",
              "tasks": [
                {
                  "_id": ObjectId("e..."),
                  "description": "task_id_1"  // Reference to translations collection
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// Translations collection
{
  "_id": ObjectId("task_id_1"),
  "translations": {
    "en": {
      "description": "White cabbage is a common vegetable crop, one of the cultivated variants of the species Brassica oleracea."
    },
    "es": {
      "description": "La col blanca es un cultivo de hortalizas común, una de las variantes cultivadas de la especie Brassica oleracea."
    }
    // Add more translations as needed
  }
}
```

Translations can be saved in a separate collection and referenced in the main document this manner. You can use a lookup to retrieve translations while searching for a certain course or activity. You can effectively search tasks by ID by creating an index on the tasks' _id field. MongoDB constructs an index on the _id column automatically, thus you don't need to do anything unusual for it. MongoDB will use the index for quick lookups when querying jobs by _id.

```
db.courses.findOne({
  "modules.lessons.topics.tasks._id": ObjectId("e...")
},
{
  "modules.lessons.topics.tasks.$": 1
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your example! Could you tell me, If I need translations of texts and the document size exceeds 16MB, what should I do? And the second question is what is the best way to find `tasks[$id]` in the collection?

Comment: If you require text translations and the document size exceeds 16MB, you might wish to explore a design in which translations are stored in a separate collection and referenced to the main content. You may keep the primary document smaller and more manageable this way.